# How to mount ext4 fs with block size of 65536?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, ext4

I am benchmarking EXT4 performance on Compact Flash media.

I have created an ext4 fs with block size of 65536. However I cannot
mount it on ubuntu-10.10-netbook-i386 (it is already mounting ext4 fs with 4096 bytes of block sizes)

According to my readings on ext4 it should allow such big block sized
fs. I want to hear your comments.

```
root@ubuntu:~# mkfs.ext4 -b 65536  /dev/sda3
Warning: blocksize 65536 not usable on most systems.
mke2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
mkfs.ext4: 65536-byte blocks too big for system (max 4096)
Proceed anyway? (y,n) y
Warning: 65536-byte blocks too big for system (max 4096), forced to continue
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=65536 (log=6)
Fragment size=65536 (log=6)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
19968 inodes, 19830 blocks
991 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
1 block group
65528 blocks per group, 65528 fragments per group
19968 inodes per group

Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (1024 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

This filesystem will be automatically checked every 37 mounts or
180 days, whichever comes first.  Use tune2fs -c or -i to override.



root@ubuntu:~# tune2fs -l /dev/sda3
tune2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          <not available>
Filesystem UUID:          4cf3f507-e7b4-463c-be11-5b408097099b
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index
filetype extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg
dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash
Default mount options:    (none)
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              19968
Block count:              19830
Reserved block count:     991
Free blocks:              18720
Free inodes:              19957
First block:              0
Block size:               65536
Fragment size:            65536
Blocks per group:         65528
Fragments per group:      65528
Inodes per group:         19968
Inode blocks per group:   78
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Sat Feb  5 14:39:55 2011
Last mount time:          n/a
Last write time:          Sat Feb  5 14:40:02 2011
Mount count:              0
Maximum mount count:      37
Last checked:             Sat Feb  5 14:39:55 2011
Check interval:           15552000 (6 months)
Next check after:         Thu Aug  4 14:39:55 2011
Lifetime writes:          70 MB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:               256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      afb5b570-9d47-4786-bad2-4aacb3b73516
Journal backup:           inode blocks


root@ubuntu:~# mount -t ext4 /dev/sda3 /mnt/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda3,
      missing codepage or helper program, or other error
      In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
      dmesg | tail  or so
```

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK ext2/3/4 is based on the generic Linux VFS framework which requires block size to be less than or equal to page size

> You may experience mounting problems if block size is greater than page size (i.e. 64KiB blocks on a i386 which only has 4KiB memory pages).
>
> https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ext4/overview.html

There were some talks regarding solving the big block issue

- [Large pages, large blocks, and large problems](https://lwn.net/Articles/250335/)
- [Design for Large Allocation Blocks](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Design_for_Large_Allocation_Blocks)
- [RFC: CONFIG_PAGE_SHIFT (aka software PAGE_SIZE)](https://lwn.net/Articles/240914/)

Unfortunately there's almost no great progress yet

---

However since you just want to test the speed, I suggest to **use [bigalloc](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Bigalloc)** which allocates in big clusters instead of big blocks. For example to create an ext4 partition with 64KB cluster

```bsh
dd if=/dev/zero of=ext4.bigalloc bs=1M count=256
mkfs.ext4 -C 65535 -O bigalloc ext4.bigalloc
sudo mount -o loop ext4.bigalloc /mnt
```

This option is new in [Linux 3.2](https://lwn.net/Articles/469805/) kernel and you must specify that option when calling `mkfs.ext4` as seen above

> - `-C` cluster-size
>
>   - Specify  the  size  of cluster in bytes for filesystems using the bigalloc feature. Valid cluster-size values are from 2048 to 256M bytes per cluster. This can only be  specified if the bigalloc feature is enabled. (See the [ext4 (5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/ext4.5.html) man page for more details about bigalloc.) The default cluster size if bigalloc is enabled  is 16 times the block size.
>
> http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/mke2fs.8.html

This feature is [still in development](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html) so use it with care. But since you typically don't care about file corruption while benchmarking, it's probably the best option

---

That said, the limit is just in the in-kernel driver and you can still mount the partition with the **FUSE driver**. Some examples:

- [Fuse-ext2](https://github.com/alperakcan/fuse-ext2)

  > Fuse-ext2 is an EXT2/EXT3/EXT4 filesystem for FUSE, and is built to work with osxfuse.

  ```
  Usage:    fuse-ext2 <device|image_file> <mount_point> [-o option[,...]]

  Options:  ro, rw+, force, allow_other
            Please see details in the manual.

  Example:  fuse-ext2 /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1
  ```

  Just run `sudo apt install fuseext2` to install if it's not available. Tested on my system and it works perfectly
- [guestmount](https://libguestfs.org/guestmount.1.html). See how to use it in [Possible to mount an ext4 partition image via FUSE?](https://serverfault.com/a/917007/343888)

If you just want to *copy* the data then you can use [debugfs](https://linux.die.net/man/8/debugfs) but it's not quite useful for benchmarking. Even the performance of FUSE may be not good enough for measuring the device speed

Comment: Here is a reference to Bigalloc from Linux Kernel Wiki: https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Bigalloc

Answer (score 2):

The max ext4 block size is still limited by the page size of the kernel/CPU. Your page size is 4K and so the max ext4 block size is 4K.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say use 4KB blocks for compatibility and use extents and stripe stride-width options on create/mount to get block allocations in accordance with the erase block size of your flash media.

Make sure also that the partition is aligned to this erase block size too!